# android textview is doubled/mirrored/masked after restarting the app

Tags: android, textview

[image]
This is what happens after:

1) I open my app, perform some regular actions.
2) Close my app, (killing fragments and activity).
3) Reopen my app from the application drawer.

I have a feeling that it's something I'm doing in the lifecycle events.
Does anyone encountered that? whats wrong?

Code of the Activity (views initialization)

```
public class PlayClient extends Activity {
public static Context ctx = null;

private String TAG = "PlayClient Activity";

private Fragment main;
private Fragment mSoundCloudFrag;
private MediaControlsComponent mdc;

private FragmentManager fm;

private String[] mNavigationItems;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    ctx = this;

    // Sound Cloud fragment
    mSoundCloudFrag = new SoundCloudFragment();

    // Add just the main player fragment
    main = new Play_Main();
    mdc = new MediaControlsComponent();


    fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.frameContainer, main, "main");
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
    ft.add(R.id.mediaControllerFrame, mdc);
    ft.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();


    // Navigation Drawer
    mNavigationItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

Code of the fragment

```
public class Play_Main extends Fragment implements IListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Play_Main_Fragment";
    public static CountDownLatch mCountDown = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private Typeface roboto;

    // Views
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView pullToConnect;
    private Button connectButton;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;


    // Object Instances
    private Play_Main mainFrag;
    private MessageManager messageManager;

    // Animation
    private Animation fadeIn;
    private Animation fadeOut;

    // Fields
    private String isConnectedText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_ui_frame, container, false);
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, null);

        mainFrag = this;
        final Gson jsonMaker = new Gson();

        roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/robotot.ttf");

        fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_out);
        fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_in);

        messageManager = MessageManager.Instance();
        // Register as a general listener
        messageManager.RegisterListener(mainFrag);
        // Register as the UI to interact with
        messageManager.registerUI(mainFrag);

        pullToConnect = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pullToConnect);
        pullToConnect.setTypeface(roboto);

        tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setTypeface(roboto);
        tv1.setText("Connect and start playing");


        mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        mSwipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```

XML of Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="@color/darker"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="80"></FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mediaControllerFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="20"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML of fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pullToConnect"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/pull_to_connect"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="23dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Without seeing code (specifically the xml and the java where you actually initialize the layout/view) it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Are you adding or replacing the fragment with the TextView? I've seen this happen with just adding a fragment on create/resume methods, especially if using setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: Thank you I've added the code. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes I am manipulating the fragment with the fragment manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.add(R.id.frameContainer, main, "main");
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
ft.add(R.id.mediaControllerFrame, mdc);
ft.commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

You should only do this Fragment initialization on the *first* call to `onCreate()`. The `FragmentManager` handles retaining your fragments across configuration changes, so if you were to rotate the screen, `onCreate()` will be called again, and you will add another instance of `main` and `mdc` on top of the old ones, each time.

Instead, wrap your fragment initialization code in a null check with `savedInstanceState`. If `savedInstanceState` is null, that means it's the first creation of your Activity:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.frameContainer, main, "main");
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
    ft.add(R.id.mediaControllerFrame, mdc);
    ft.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind - should I always create a new instance of the class holding the fragment? or can I share the instance. I mean, lets say I initialized the fragment class once and then the user performed an onClick and then I've added a different fragment. Now lets say the user clicked on something to load the previous fragment again - should I use a new instance of the fragment class or can I re-use the reference of the old one?

Comment: I always just use a new one, honestly. It's usually not worth the complexity of trying to keep them around, and it can lead to some subtle bugs. Unless your fragment is really expensive to create, I'd just stick with making a new one.